# Trigger an accordian menu with Media Queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm wondering if it would be possible to trigger a jQuery accordion menu, at a specific viewport stated in CSS3 Media Queries.

**EG;** For mobile devices, below 450px width viewport > the normal menu disappears > and a jQuery accordian menu appears in it's place.

How could I get this done? Is there a way I could set a conditional for viewports as doable for IE, that could hide that menu, and pull in my new jQuery accordion one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could simply have the menu and the accordion on two separate divs, and change their `display` CSS property to either `block` or `none` depending on the viewport width, like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 450px) {
    .accordion { display: block; }
    .normalmenu { display: none; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 450px) {
    .accordion { display: none; }
    .normalmenu { display: block; }
}
```

If your accordion and menu have the same HTML structure, you could listen for the window resize event and load the accordion; of course, you should also check it on the initial load:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidthAndLoadAccordion();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkWidthAndLoadAccordion();
});

function checkWidthAndLoadAccordion() {
    if($(window).width() < 450) {
        // load your accordion
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.